# Exclude link when clicking tr

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here's the page:
http://nm-bootstrap.gydev.com/course-delivery.php

Both the chevron toggle icons and the bookmark icons on the title rows are prepended to the first th.  I have some js in place to toggle the following rows if a tr with th is clicked.

The problem is that I need to exclude that bookmark (an `<a>` with a class of "bookmark-this") from the event, since someone needs to be able to bookmark and entire section without toggling the rows below.  So the entire row EXCEPT the bookmark should trigger the event.

Here is the jQuery making it work

```
$("#table-modules tbody tr:not(.section-title)").hide();

$("#table-modules tbody tr.section-title").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.section-title').toggle().end()
        .find('.icon-chevron-right').toggle().end()
        .find('.icon-chevron-down').toggle();
});

$(".bookmark-this").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.icon-bookmark-empty').toggle().end()
        .find('.icon-bookmark').toggle();
});
```

and here are the first 2 rows of rendered html

```
<tr class="section-title" style="cursor: pointer; ">
<th><i class="icon-chevron-right grayLight"></i><i class="icon-chevron-down grayLight" style="display: none; "></i><a class="bookmark-this"><i class="icon-bookmark-empty grayLight"></i><i class="icon-bookmark red" style="display: none; "></i></a>1. Introduction</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>11:53</th>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none; ">
<td style="padding-left: 45px; "><a class="bookmark-this"><i class="icon-bookmark-empty grayLight"></i><i class="icon-bookmark red" style="display: none; "></i></a><a href="#">How to take an online course</a></td>
<td><img src="/img/icons/check-sm.png" width="16" height="13" alt="yes"></td>
<td>6:32</td>
</tr>
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Using `<i>` for a style-only tag is strange; it's interpreted as italics, and therefore some kind of emphasis. If you want a do-nothing tag that you can style, you should use `<span>` (or `<div>` if you want a `display: block;` element). This is important for things like screen-readers (used by the blind), and is in general a better practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `stopPropagation` to the click handler of `.bookmark-this`

```
$(".bookmark-this").click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation() });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the not selector

```
$("#table-modules tbody tr.section-title:not(.bookmark-this)").click
```

Comment: actually this won't work. I didn't look close enough at your DOM structure...I think stopPropagation as kei suggested is the correct way to do this